# Convert Eloquent HasMany relationship to a HasOne?

Tags: eloquent, relationship, has-many, has-one

Ok, i have model `A` that is linked to many model `B`, so model `A` have a `hasMany` relationship to model `B` and model `B` has a `belongsTo` relationship to model `A`.

But, amongst all those `B` there is a particular one, e.g. the one with the higher value, that i want model `A` to have a dedicated relationship with.

I know i can create a second relationship in model `A` that re-use the old one and add all the scopes and condition i want, but since i'm building this new relationship from a `hasMany`, it will return always, no matter what, a collection of results.

Is there a way to have it return a single result instead than a collection? I know i can add a `first()`, but this involve in using this new relationship  as a function, i.e. always with parenthesis, and if possible i would like to still use it the eloquent way.

Is it possible to do that? if yes, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

```php
public function Bs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(B::class);
}

public function B()
{
    $builder = $this->Bs()->latest(); // Add your own conditions etc...

    $relation = new HasOne($builder->getQuery(), $this, 'a_id', 'id');

    return $relation; // or return $relation->withDefault();
}
```

**Update:**

A new *one-of-many* relationship shipped with Laravel 8.42. You probably want to use this instead:

```php
public function B(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(B::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa, this is really interesting, i'll keep it in mind the next time; maybe with more complex use cases this will came in help.

Answer (score 1):

Not really no. You have 2 models mapping tables with some attributes as follow

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
| id  | id  |
| ... | a_id|
|     | ... |
+-----+-----+
```

When you call onto the `hasMany` relationship, the builder executes a query. Something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM `B` WHERE `B`.`a_id` = ?
```

If you make a different relationship for it, you will only duplicate the query (if you load both relationships). You could make an `accessor`, or just use `first()`.

**EDIT** Accessor code:

```php
# A model
public function getXAttribute()
{
    // Query only if necessary
    if(!this->relationLoaded('b')) $this->load('b');
    // Use Collection methods to filter
    return $this->b->firstWhere(...);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer; so you mean i need to make a second `hasOne` relatioship fro `A` to `B` with the correct conditions to get the exact `b` i want?

Comment: No, just ab accessor something like`getXAttribute() { if(!this->relationLoaded('b'){ $this->load('b'); } returns $this->b->firstWhere(...); }`